# Broadcast Exception with laravel pusher

Tags: laravel-5.4, pusher

I'm using pusher with laravel 5.4 .
I installed pusher using : 
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~2.6"
after that  I make the  necessary changes in .env , config/App.php and config/Broadcasting.php . I create TaskEvent :

```
<?php
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;


class TaskEvent implements ShouldBroadcast

{

  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public $message;
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message=$message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('testChannel');
    }
}
```

then , in routes/web.php :

```
use App\Events\TaskEvent;

Route::get('event',function(){
    event(new TaskEvent('hello world'));
});
```

but I'm getting this error :

```
(1/1) BroadcastException

in PusherBroadcaster.php (line 106)
```

Please help me !!!

Comment: this is known issue.. check https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16478